# Copy Android studio installed app to new device

Tags: android, apk, apk-signing

I have written an android app, and installed onto an Api25 phone (debug build) via Android Studio.
Now I have been forced to get a new device while away from home.

I would like to copy the app from my old to new device, while not having access to my computer or source code.

I have been able to grab the APK which is unsigned (or signed with development debug keys)
However upon install on the new device "the package appears to be invalid"

Neither device has root.
How can I resign this apk without a computer (device only).
This is a personal app I use for work so package names etc are of no concern.

Comment: You cannot open a debug build independently in a mobile device. It needs to be a release build

Comment: BTW, the "invalid package" error suggests a problem with APK itself. This issue might be due to the APK being corrupted during the copy process or compatibility issues with  new device. Also check if the new device's settings allow installation from unknown sources.

Comment: `have tried simply copying the APK from /storage/emulated/0/Android/data` Your apk is not in that location to begin with. Unclear what you tried.

Comment: Your apk is not signed. So even if you manage to grab it you can not install it on another device.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I have edited the question. I used Total commander to copy the APK.

Comment: @blackapps thank you for nailing down the problem. I have edited the question to reflect your comment

Comment: For signing it doesn't matter if it runs in a PC or directly on Android. The code for signing is provided by Google in apksig Java library so it is pretty easy to integrate it in an app. As app recommendations are off-topic here I can simply say to search for an APK resigning app, you will find them.

Comment: After resigning the APK I now receive the warnings that it was designed for an older version of android before the package is invalid. I have abandoned the question because the next opportunity to work on the problem will be when I get home by then of course the issue is moot. Thank you for your help folks.